# Write an SQL code to find the projects belonging to a single Epic

Tags: sql

We have a projects table with the following data:

| project_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-05 |
| 102 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-01-08 |
| 103 | 2020-01-09 | 2020-01-13 |
| 104 | 2020-01-16 | 2020-01-17 |
| 105 | 2020-01-18 | 2020-01-20 |
| 106 | 2020-01-24 | 2020-01-28 |
| 107 | 2020-01-29 | 2020-01-30 |

A particular set of projects belong to a common epic if the start_date of the next project is 1 day after the end date of the previous one. As an example, 101,102, and 103 belong to a single epic since 102's start_date is 2020-01-06, which is 1 day after 101's end_date 2020-01-05. Similarly, 103's start_date is 2020-01-09, which is 1 day after 102's end_date 2020-01-08

The following result table has to be obtained

| epic | projects | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101;102;103 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-13 |
| 2 | 104;105 | 2020-01-16 | 2020-01-20 |
| 3 | 106;107 | 2020-01-24 | 2020-01-30 |

I somehow feel this is a gaps and islands problem but I am not able to isolate them. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.

Comment: Imagine that you have 3 projects. 1st ends at 2020-12-31, 2nd and 3rd starts at 2021-01-01. What is the epic - 1,2 or 1,3? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A particular set of projects belong to a common epic if the start_date of the next project is 1 day after the end date of the previous one.

You can use `lag()` and a cumulative sum.  The following uses SQL Server syntax:

```
select epic,
       string_agg(project_id, ',') within group (order by project_id) as project_ids,
       min(start_date), max(end_date)
from (select p.*,
             sum(case when prev_end_date is null or prev_end_date = dateadd(day, -1, start_date
                      then 0 else 1
                 end) over (order by start_date) as epic
      from (select p.*,
                   lag(end_date) over (order by start_date) as prev_end_date
            from projects p
           ) p
     ) p
group by epic
order by epic;
```